# How do I search multiple databases at once?

Tags: mysql, database, search, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have imported many different databases into my wamp local host. It uses phpmyadmin and I am wondering if there is an easy way to search for let's say an email address from every table in every database at once, or tables I choose but from different databases. Is there a php script I can use that is similar to leaked source that could act like a search engine for the databases I have on my local host? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `union all` for each database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Prasanna mentioned above, you can use `UNION` across the tables:

```
SELECT option_value
 FROM `database1`.`table1`
  WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT option_value2
 FROM `database2`.`table2`
  WHERE ..;
```

**OR** you can do something like below, if you're searching within a specific table and schema:

```
SELECT table_schema 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'table1' AND column_name = 'id';
```

Comment: exactly true @Kulasangar

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ yes indeed. :)

Comment: That's very helpful but what would I put down for wp_options? UNION seems like the best way to go about things so far!

Comment: @JohnC instead of wp_options, insert your table names. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Kulasangar That's very helpful! May I add you on skype and maybe tomorrow you can help me with a mini project and Ill pay you xD

Comment: @Kulasangar and also, where in that code would I type the string I wanna search for?

Comment: @Kulasangar just want to know where I would put the string that i want to search for in the selected databases and tables

Comment: @JohnC you mean to search for the values ?

Comment: But make sure you connect using a `user account` that has access to all the databases you want to access

Comment: @Kulasangar What I am trying to do is search for an email in database_1 table_2 and database_2 table_1 for example. where in the code would I put the email?